# How can I validate worldwide postal codes in my .NET code

Tags: .net, validation, zipcode, postal-code

I am looking for a way to validate worldwide postal codes in my .NET project, and I don't really want to come up and maintain regular expressions for the whole world.

Preferably I would want to pull in a dependency to a library or in the worst case use some web based service (but that would really be a last resort).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [PostalCodes.Net](https://github.com/Cimpress-MCP/PostalCodes.Net) package on github.

It support most countries and has a good interface. Here is an example:

```
var country = CountryFactory.Instance.CreateCountry("PL");
var postalCode = PostalCodeFactory.Instance.CreatePostalCode(country, "44-100");
```

Comment: Seems like when the postal code is invalid you will get `ArgumentException` with the message describing the reason.